# Scraping images from a webpage and saving it to a customized folder using vba

Tags: vba, image, web-scraping

I've written a script in VBA which is able to scrape images from a webpage and save it to a customized folder successfully. Firstly, it scrapes the image link then downloads the image and rename it according to it's identity. It takes 2/3 seconds to accomplish the task. I tried to do the whole thing specklessly. Here is the script I tried with:

```
Sub SavingImages()

Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim htmlas As Object, htmla As Object, html As Object
Dim stream As Object, tempArr As Variant
Dim fileSource As String

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/", False
    .send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set htmlas = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("movie")

For Each htmla In htmlas
    Set html = htmla.getElementsByTagName("img")(0)

    fileSource = Replace(html.src, "about", "http")
    tempArr = Split(html.src, "/")
    tempArr = tempArr(UBound(tempArr))

    With http
        .Open "GET", fileSource, False
        .send
    End With

    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    stream.Open
    stream.Type = 1
    stream.write http.responseBody
    stream.SaveToFile ("D:\Test\Images\" & tempArr & ".jpg")
    stream.Close
Next htmla
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is quite clear to read and understand. There are only minor things I would improve:

- better variable names - `tempArr`, for example, is a bad name - what about:

  ```
  fileSource = Replace(html.src, "about", "http")
  urlParts = Split(html.src, "/")
  imageFileName = urlParts(UBound(urlParts))
  ```

  and then use `imageFileName` instead of `tempArr` later on. Also think of better names for `htmla` and `htmlas`.
- you can use `with` for the `stream` variable as well
- avoid "hardcoding" - define "D:\Test\Images\" path as a constant, or as a parameter for your function
- you can also iterate over the `img` elements directly if you do:

  ```
  Set movieImages = htmldoc.querySelectorAll(".movie img")
  ```

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your suggestion to do the betterment of my script.    It feels good to get the accreditation of my script from a giant coder like you. Thanks again.